# Is a cursor the only alternative to do this kind of operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-cursor

I'm trying to optimize a long transaction and I've seen that the following is done quite a few times:

```
Declare @myCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT field1, MIN(COALESCE(field2, -2)) FROM MyTable tempfact
LEFT JOIN MyTable sd
ON tempfact.ID = sd.ID AND sd.TransactionId = @transactionId
WHERE tempfact.SomeField IS NULL
AND tempfact.TransactionId = @transactionId
GROUP BY tempfact.field1

OPEN @myCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM @myCursor INTO @field1Variable, @field2Variable

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   EXEC USP_SOME_PROC @field1Variable, @field2Variable
   FETCH NEXT FROM @myCursor INTO @field1Variable, @field2Variable
END

CLOSE @myCursor
DEALLOCATE @myCursor
```

The code for the USP_SOME_PROC sproc is as follows:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Field1 = @field1)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO SomeTable (Field1, Field2)
   VALUES (@field1, @field2)
END
```

Like I mentioned this is done in quite a few places, tables and fields involved are different but the idea remains the same, and I'm sure that there might be a way to increase the performance of these sprocs if cursors are not used and probably by making this transaction faster an issue that we're having with a deadlock (a subject for another post) might be solved.

Comment: 99 times out of 100, cursor logic can be transformed into set based logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `MERGE` for this

```
;WITH Source AS
(
SELECT field1,
       MIN(COALESCE(field2, -2)) as field2
FROM   MyTable tempfact
       LEFT JOIN MyTable sd
         ON tempfact.ID = sd.ID
            AND sd.TransactionId = @transactionId
WHERE  tempfact.SomeField IS NULL
       AND tempfact.TransactionId = @transactionId
GROUP  BY tempfact.field1  
)
MERGE SomeTable AS T
USING Source S
ON (T.Field1 = S.Field1)


WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Field1, Field2)
    VALUES (field1, field2)
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to test this, but this should be close: you need to insert from a SELECT statement but also need to make sure that a corresponding record doesn't already exist in SomeTable

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (Field1, Field2)
SELECT field1, MIN(COALESCE(field2, -2)) 
FROM MyTable tempfact 
    LEFT JOIN MyTable sd ON tempfact.ID = sd.ID AND sd.TransactionId = @transactionId 
    LEFT JOIN SomeTable st ON st.Field1 = tempfact.field1
WHERE tempfact.SomeField IS NULL 
    AND tempfact.TransactionId = @transactionId 
    AND st.Field1 IS NULL
GROUP BY tempfact.field1
```

Comment: There is a possibility of a race condition here under default `read committed` isolation level.

Comment: Hey Martin, could you elaborate or post some links on what your commenting here please?

Comment: @Sergio- The `SELECT` statement will only take shared locks and then release them as soon as the data is read so it is possible for another transaction to insert a row with one of the same `field1` values after the `select` has already concluded that row doesn't exist. So then you would end up with two rows with the same `field1` value (or an error if this has a unique constraint enforced)

Comment: @Martin- Thank you so much. I found this blog that, even though it seems that merge might also cause a race condition it is easier to prevent and it does behave better than SELECT in this case. [link](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)

Comment: @Sergio - Thanks. That is very interesting. I was always of the impression that using `MERGE` automatically handled the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need not have a cursor and can use bulk insert logic something like below

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (Field1, Field2) 
SELECT 
       field1,       
       MIN(COALESCE(field2, -2)) 
FROM
      MyTable tempfact        
LEFT JOIN 
      MyTable sd          
           ON tempfact.ID = sd.ID             
              AND sd.TransactionId = @transactionId 
WHERE  
      tempfact.SomeField IS NULL        
      AND tempfact.TransactionId = @transactionId 
GROUP  BY 
      tempfact.field1
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I thought the exact same thing at first but you seem to have skipped over the `IF NOT EXISTS` check in the procedure too.